# UIPageViewController does not rotate: iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uipageviewcontroller

Although I setted :

```
AppDelegate* delegate = (AppDelegate*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
allowLandscape = YES;
```

And in delegates:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {                    
     return YES;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
     return YES;
}
```

My `UIPageViewController` **does not rotate on device rotation**.

I want to point that whit **iOS7** all works great!

I also try to manually set orientation, no way:

```
 [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft] forKey:@"orientation"];
```